# Can I get a List from an object, add a String to it, and set it back to the object in one line?

Tags: java, list

I was wondering if one can get a `List` from an object, add an item to it, and set the `List` to the object **in one line**.

I would normally do it this way:

```
List<String> tempList = someObject.getList();
tempList.add("some string value");
someObject.setList(tempList);
```

What I tried doing was this:

```
someObject.setList(someObject.getList().add("some string value"));
```

But then I realized that the method `add()` would return a boolean while the method `setList()` takes a `List<String>`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you aren't returning a copy in `getList` it should be the same reference, so you can say

```
someObject.getList().add("some string value");
```

And you should not need to `setList` back, because there is only one `List`.

Comment: May you offer more explanation on how it works. I was not aware that we could manipulate objects by reference in Java.

Comment: [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) Java is always pass by value, but the value of objects (reference types) **is-a** reference.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there is no nice way to do this in one line.

If you need to do this a lot, you could modify the class of `someObject` to have an `addItem` method to do this directly.

Alternatively, if you cannot modify the class, you could write a method for adding to a list and returning the list:

```
static <E> List<E> add(List<E> list, E extra) {
    list.add(extra);
    return list; 
}
```

Comment: +1 for a simple solution. I knew I could do this, but wanted to know if I could do it directly without creating new methods.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you ***can*** do something in one statement, doesn't mean you ***should***!

But it's certainly possible if you don't mind abusing the streams a little bit:

```
    Stream.of(someObject.getList())
            .map(list -> new Pair<>(list.add(new Object()), list))
            .forEach(pair -> someObject.setList(pair.getValue()));
```

Of course the real answer is, if you want to do things like this in one line you should simply write a method with as many lines as needed for clarity, then call it (in one line).